# i am not getting hamburger menu bar to work

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

```
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="#" class="logo">Bizsot</a>
        <div class="menu-toggle"></div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </header>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(funtion(){
                $('.menu-toggle').click(funtion(){ 
                 $('.menu-toggle').toggleclass('active')
                 $('nav').toggleclass('active')
        })
        </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

**how can i get my hamburger menu to work my hamburger menu wont drop down i tried fiddling with javascript code in html but it does works whats the matter**

Comment: can we all see your css, man?

Comment: also why ur menu-toggle div is empty? there should be something in there i guess

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {})` - you have a typo **funtion** -> **function** (also here: `$('.menu-toggle').click(funtion() {})` )